# How to recreate this motion?

Tags: after-effects, motion-graphics

Recently saw [this](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bl6sWSBnevz/) motion graphics on Instagram which reveals a Malayalam letter. I assume it is created using After Effects.

How could I create something similar like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author in the comments says it was made using Cinema4D.

It looks a lot like this tutorial:

http://cgterminal.com/2017/08/10/cinema-4d-hyper-realistic-3d-acrylic-paint-stroke-tutorial/